# Функция возвращает пустой результат

Tags: postgresql

Вот процедура:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getBooks(bookId integer)
 LANGUAGE sql
 AS $$
 SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = bookId;
 $$;
```

Создаём таблицу books:

```
CREATE TABLE books(id INTEGER NOT NULL, bookName varchar(30) NOT NULL)
```

Вот то, что мы добавляем в таблицу books:

```
INSERT INTO books(id, bookName) VALUES (2, 'c life');
```

А вот пример использования:

```
call getBooks(2);
```

Но почему-то не возвращает таблицу, а просто слово CALL:

```
 CALL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Процедуры не возвращают значений. Вам похоже нужна функция:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (
  id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, name TEXT
)
;
-- CREATE TABLE

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f() RETURNS SETOF t AS
$$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM t;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
;
-- CREATE FUNCTION

INSERT INTO t (name) VALUES ('johnsmith');
-- INSERT 0 1

SELECT * FROM f();
-- -[ RECORD 1 ]
-- id   | 1
-- name | johnsmith
```